# ¿Como sacer el promedio de fechas en SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta a una tabla en SQL Server la cual me da el siguiente resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero lo que necesito es que se sumen las columnas Ha, Pronostico, Entregado y Diferencia, y de las columnas de Fechas se saque un prmedio para que solo me arroje un resultado.
Aqui mi query

```html
SELEECT
  *,
  (A.Pronostico/A.Entregado) as Diferencia
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      Codigo,
      Nombre,
      sum(Ha) as Ha,
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), fechaplantacion,23) AS Fechaplantacion,
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Fechacorte1,23) AS  Fechacorte1, 
      sum(Pronostico) as
      Pronostico, sum(Entregado) as Entregado
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY...
)A
```

Resultado esperado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Necesitas el promedio de las columnas `ha`, `pronostico`, `entregado` y `diferencia` agrupados por fecha?

Comment: Necesito el promedio de los resultados de las columnas  Fechacorte1 y Fecha plantacion @DamiánAlva

Comment: si es posible, coloca el resultado esperado para las tuplas de la imagen porque no entiendo mucho lo que necesitas

Comment: listo @DamiánAlva

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En principio, no puedes obtener un promedio de fechas, es algo que no tiene sentido. Lo que si puedes, es obtener el promedio de la diferencia en días de una fecha con respecto a otra fecha de referencia y luego transformar esta diferencia en una fecha. Por ejemplo:

**¿Cuál sería el promedio entre estas dos fechas: `2019-06-19` y `2019-06-21`?** si imaginamos que debiera ser `2019-06-20`, la solución sería algo así:

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(DAY, '1970-01-01', '2019-06-19') Dia1,
        DATEDIFF(DAY, '1970-01-01', '2019-06-21') Dia2,
        (DATEDIFF(DAY, '1970-01-01', '2019-06-19') + DATEDIFF(DAY, '1970-01-01', '2019-06-21')) / 2 'Promedio'

Dia1        Dia2        Promedio
----------- ----------- -----------
18066       18068       18067
```

El valor 18067 es el promedio, ahora lo transformamos en una fecha:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 18067, '1970-01-01') 'FechaPromedio'

FechaPromedio
-----------------------
2019-06-20 00:00:00.000
```

En tu caso sería algo así:

```
SELECT Codigo,
       Nombre,
       sum(Ha) as Ha,
       DATEADD(DAY,avg(DATEDIFF(DAY, '19000101', fechaplantacion)), '19000101') as fechaplantacion,
       DATEADD(DAY,avg(DATEDIFF(DAY, '19000101', Fechacorte1)), '19000101') as Fechacorte1,
       sum(Pronostico) as Pronostico, 
       sum(Entregado) as Entregado
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY Codigo, Nombre
```

En este caso, la fecha de referencia la llevé al que parece tu valor mínimo `1900-01-01`.

#### Comentario aparte

Francamente no sé que puede aportarte un promedio en el caso de las fechas, básicamente te da una ubicación de la centralidad de la muestra de fechas, si las fechas tienen algún sesgo, el promedio no te da una idea real de dónde esta la fecha media. Tal vez te sea más cercano a lo que buscas, dividir por dos la diferencia en días entre la fecha más antigua y la más actual, algo como esto:

```
DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(Fechacorte1), MAX(Fechacorte1)) / 2, MIN(fecha))
```